# Ebay Finding API

Tags: java, ebay-api

I am making a call from a server that is located in US to FindItemsAdvanced of ebay finding api.

I define ListedIn as `"EBAY-ENCA"`, however, when I make the call - I see that it doesn't return results. I believe that this is because that items are not available to US.

I see that there is a parameter called: `AvailableTo` - but how can I say "to all countries" ? Writing each iso code in the world could be exhausting..

My code:

```
  ItemFilter marketFilter = new ItemFilter();
    marketFilter.setName(ItemFilterType.LISTED_IN);
    marketFilter.getValue().add("EBAY-ENCA");
    request.getItemFilter().add(marketFilter);
    ItemFilter conditionFilter = new ItemFilter();
    conditionFilter.setName(ItemFilterType.AVAILABLE_TO);
    conditionFilter.getValue().add("UK");
    request.getItemFilter().add(conditionFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

In general this call should work - regardless from where you call the API. So I assume that you get an error message from the API that prevent items from being returned. Be aware that the FindItemsAdvanced call of the eBay Finding API requires either a given "categoryId" or a "keyword". Do you set any of these?

Here is the XML payload of a working call:

```
<findItemsAdvancedRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <keywords>iPhone6</keywords>
    <itemFilter>
        <name>ListedIn</name>
        <value>EBAY-ENCA</value>
    </itemFilter>
</findItemsAdvancedRequest>
```

I've created an example in our [API playground](https://sdk.intradesys.com/s/f4b9ec30ad9f68f89b29639786cb62ef). It uses the XML version of the Finding API. Just execute the call to see the valid response with items included. You can adapt and customize the request parameters to your needs and see how the API responses.

The "AvailableTo" filter can only be used once per request with exactly one value. So it won't be possible to add it multiple times or to add it once with multiple values. But I'm not sure if I get your use case right. Do you really want to get only those items that are available world wide? If yes, then I'm afraid this most probably isn't possible without filtering them locally (eg. by filtering for "Worldwide" in the "shipToLocations").

Comment: Thanks. I do see a difference if I make a call from my local machine - which is in one country, than if I make a call from server that is in the US. I am using Ebay SDK for Java, and I see in the result the item result url as: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1&LH_FS=1&_fls=1&_incaucbin=0&_ipg=100&_li=3&_os=S%7CA%7CC%7CST%7CD&_sop=15&_nkw=Gucci+1627+sunglasses+black .

Comment: If I add the availableTo param, I will get this link with more products http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=1&LH_FS=1&_fls=1&_incaucbin=0&_ipg=100&_li=3&_os=S%7CA%7CC%7CST%7CD&_sop=15&_nkw=Gucci+1627+sunglasses+black&LH_AvailTo=3

Comment: The call works, but returns different elements based on where the call was made from